# How I do run gnome app and let it run via SSH even after SSH closed?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I found that, exporting DISPLAY=:0.0 and starting a gnome app (xclock) would run on remote machine. The issue , when i log out of SSH, the xclock closes on the remote machine. I wanted it run there until i quit or kill it from remote machine itself. Is there way achieve it ?.

Comment: Why not just leave SSH running in the background?

Comment: bcoz, i use laptop from home to access office desktop and while traveling to office, laptop would be closed and connection closes.

Comment: I am sorry, but using X11 without SSH will not change anything about that.  The applications you start via X11 will still disconnect when you move to a different network.  It sounds like what you really need is something like [freenx](http://freenx.berlios.de/).

Comment: Zoredache: thats the issue, sometimes freenx itself closes which i started while i'm at work. So, to start those, i need to use ssh. Also, there is issue with 11.04 vino server. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/772304...  thats also doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the X Server is on the *remote* machine. Then you just need to filter the HUP signal with `nohup`.

Another nice command is `screen` which lets you reconnect to older sessions. Its worth a look when you often use SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are tunneling X through ssh which would explain why it shuts down with ssh.  You will need to configure your X client to access the server directly.

Comment: Typically, X11-over-SSH displays are allocated starting at `:10`, so `:0` is more likely to be X.org running on the physically connected display.

Comment: Thanks. How do I configure ? any steps would help.