# Keeping a Java app running when SSH is closed on Google Cloud

Tags: linux, ssh

Right now I’m running a Java app by SSH-ing to a VM on Google Cloud Compute. I issue a command to run the app and it loads a console. As soon as I terminate the SSH connection, the app shuts down. I assume this is because the console has been closed.

I would like this app (which is a server) to persist after I terminate SSH, and, at any point, I would like to be able to reconnect to the console and issue commands on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I do run gnome app and let it run via SSH even after SSH closed?](http://superuser.com/questions/291075/how-i-do-run-gnome-app-and-let-it-run-via-ssh-even-after-ssh-closed)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You state this:

> I would like this app (which is a server) to persist after I terminate
>   SSH, and, at any point, I would like to be able to reconnect to the
>   console and issue commands on the server.

Slightly vague in goals, but I will take a stab at it!

To run any command as a background process on a Linux server, you should prepend the command with [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) and append `&` to the end.

So the final command would be:

```
nohup [your command] &
```

The `nohup` means the command should ignore “hang ups” and the ampersand `&` appended to it is a shell command that tells the system to run the command as background process. More information on it’s usage [can be found here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes).

When you run a command like this, the process will run, you will be sent back to the command prompt and you can exit the terminal session or even go and do something else unrelated to that command during that terminal session.

Comment: If I want to return to the process and enter a command into the java console, how would I do that?

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to add that you can monitor output from another terminal: just run `tail -f nohup.out` in the same work. dir.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least three ways to do this: `nohup` ('no hang up'), `screen`/`tmux`, or `disown`. It's a little unclear from you question as to your need to connect to the server and interact with the daemon after you disconnect.

If this is the case, `nohup` and `disown` won't be good matches as you release the process (though it keeps running). `tmux` (and also `screen`) will keep a term running even when you.

For more info you can see the respective pages:

```
man nohup
man tux
```

[Bash disown](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html) (assuming you are running Bash, though many other shell include something similar)

Comment: Seems like there is no `disown` command on Google Cloud, at least the instance I'm using, started 2019 or late 2018. The `nohup` command works fine, but it does create an extra file which may not be wanted.

Answer (score 1):

To detach an application from its running shell, making it persist after the shell exits, use the `nohup` command.

You simply prefix your normal command with `nohup` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Also if nohub isn't working, [you can use screen](https://medium.com/@arnab.k/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session-c836010b26a3):

> > ```
> >  ssh into your remote box.
> > ```
>
> type screen Then start the process you want.
>
> > ```
> > Press Ctrl-A then Ctrl-D.
> > ```
>
> This will detach your screen session but leave your processes running.
>   You can now log out of the remote box.
>
> > ```
> > If you want to come back later, log on again and type screen -r This will resume your screen session, and you can see the output
> > ```

of

> your process.